# Covariant Return Type With Template Container

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Is it possible to make the following work? Basically I want Ptr<B> to be an acceptable return type replacement for Ptr<A>.

```
template<typename T>
class Ptr {
public:
    explicit Ptr (T * ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    T * ptr;
};


class A {
    virtual Ptr<A> foo () {
        return Ptr<A>(NULL);
    }
};

class B : public A {
    virtual Ptr<B> foo () { // BAD! Ptr<B> is not compatable
        return Ptr<B>(NULL);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the standard:

The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden function or covariant with the classes of the functions. If a function D::f overrides a function B::f, the return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:

- both are pointers to classes or references to classes
- the class in the return type of B::f is the same class as the class in the return type of D::f or, is an unambiguous direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of D::f and is accessible in D
- both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of D::f has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of B::f.

So in your example the return types are not really covariant (they are not pointers nor references) and moreover `Ptr<B>` and `Ptr<A>` are unrelated types.

So keeping foo virtual and returning `Ptr<A>` in A and `Ptr<B>` in B is not possible. If you can/are willing to drop virtual than you can use something in the lines of Cem Kalyoncu's proposal or a variation of it.

Answer (score 4):

Your can use curiously recurring templates to replace virtual function overloads with template function returns. The following article might help:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Also check the following code:

```
template <class C_>
class A_Base {
    Ptr<C_> foo() {
        return static_cast<C_*>(this)->foo_impl();
    }
}

class A : public A_Base<A> {
    Ptr<A> foo_impl() { return Ptr<A>(NULL); }
}

class B : public A_Base<B> {
   Ptr<B> foo_impl() { return Ptr<B>(NULL); }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
template<class T> class Ptr
{
...
};

template<class T> class A
{
    virtual Ptr<T> foo();
};

class B : public A<B>
{
    virtual Ptr<B> foo();
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.